# How to have event or run method after the document was Closed?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, word-addins

I have an Word AddIn (VSTO) that will process the word document after it will be closed by the user.
Unfortunately, the `DocumentBeforeClose` event is raised even in cases where the document is not really going to close.

Ex: The event is raised before a dialog box is shown to the user prompting the user to save the document. Users are asked whether they want to save with a Yes, No, and Cancel button. If the user selects Cancel, the document remains open even though a `DocumentBeforeClose` event was raised. 
For that reason is there is any way or method to make `event` or `Method` that will be `raised` or `run` after the document was closed .

I tried to do like this:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{            
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.DocumentBeforeClose += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeCloseEventHandler(this.Application_DocumentBeforeClose);

    // I want some thing like this
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.DocumentAfterClose += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentOpenEventHandler(this.Application_DocumentAfterClose);
}

public void Application_DocumentBeforeClose(Word.Document doc, ref bool Cancel)
{
    MessageBox.Show(doc.Path, "Path");            
}

// I want some thing like this
public void Application_DocumentAfterClose(string doc_Path)
{
    MessageBox.Show(doc_Path, "Path");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already said, you can't be certain with the `DocumentBeforeClose` event handler that the document is actually closed afterwards. However, you can gain full control on the close process by overriding the *File Close* command:

- Add commands to your Ribbon XML (for idMso `FileClose`):

  ```
  <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" 
            onLoad="OnLoad"> 
     <commands> 
       <command idMso="FileClose" onAction="MyClose" /> 
     </commands> 
     <ribbon startFromScratch="false"> 
       <tabs> 
          <!-- remaining custom UI goes here -->
       </tabs> 
     </ribbon> 
  </customUI>
  ```
- Providing the respective callback methods in your code:

  ```
  public void MyClose(IRibbonControl control, bool cancelDefault)
  {
      var doc = Application.ActiveDocument;
      doc.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdPromptToSaveChanges);

      // check whether the document is still open
      var isStillOpen = Application.IsObjectValid[doc];
  }
  ```

As full sample how to customize Word commands can be found on MSDN:

> **[Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633(v=office.12).aspx)**

Comment: Thank you so much for your helping @DirkVollmar .
By the way the dialog box is still prompting to the user when he close the document without saving the last changes. so I want an even that will be raised after getting the result from this prompting dialog box .

Comment: @hoss77: Sorry for the confusion, please see my edit.

Comment: Yes you are right I can run my method after this code:
`Application.ActiveDocument.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdPromptToSaveChanges);`
But the problem still there because the user maybe he will click the cancel button. And how can I know that?
or how can I show this SaveChanges box and get the `DialogResult`.

Comment: @hoss77: You should be able to verify whether the document is still open after the call to `Close`.

Comment: How can I verify r the document is still open after the call to `Close`.

Comment: Is there is any way to show this SaveChanges Dialog box and get the `DialogResult`

Comment: Thank you so much for your helping.
Hey @DirkVollmar  the `Application.ActiveDocument.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdPromptToSav‌​eChanges);` just close the Document not the Application window .
how can I close the Application window .